Exodus 16: 33-35 - what is known about ‘the Pact’?
I have been curious for some time about these few verses.
Was the pact something that was brought with Israel out of Egypt? What else might have they put in ‘the pact’?

The Pact that the OP is asking about is the Ark of the Covenant, called in Hebrew ארון העדות. Rashi on Shemos 16:33 comments:

‘והנח אתו לפני ה AND LAY IT UP BEFORE THE LORD — before the Ark; this verse, of course, was not spoken until the tent of meeting had been built and the Ark was placed therein, but it is written here in the chapter about the Manna, as being its appropriate place.

